# How to iterate through structure?

Tags: prolog

If I have a list like: `[atm(abd,bubu,ha), atm(aei),atm(xyz,huhu), atm(aabb,a,e,x)]`, how could I 'iterate' through the elements of one of the `atm` structures?

For example, for `atm(abd, bubu, ha)`, I would like to `write` `abd`, `bubu` and `ha`.

The problem is that the structures have variable length.

Is there a way to transform the structure into a list? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.

If `First` is `atm(abd,bubu,ha)` (for example), this code will split it into a list you can go through.

```
First =.. List.
```

Then, `List` will be `[atm, abd, bubu, ha]`.

IDK if this works in your particular version of PROLOG.  I'm using SWI-PROLOG.  If not, maybe your version has a similar predicate.

For more information, see http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3D..)/2 .

Comment: Yup! Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's all good, but I have to wait for the 15 minutes to pass in order to accept it. haha

Comment: @TomaRadu-Petrescu You can also use `arg/3`, as in, `arg(2, atm(abd, bubu, ha), X)` results in `X = bubu`. Or, `arg(N, atm(abd, bubu, ah), Arg)` which results in, `N = 1, Arg = abd`, `N = 2, Arg = bubu`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

## Using `(=..)/2`

@TopologicalSort has already given a nice answer, using `(=..)/2` to convert a term to a **list** of functor and arguments.

This obviously solves the immediate problem very generally.

However, it comes with its own drawbacks too: First and most importantly, `(=..)/2` is *not* a general relation. For example, we have:

```
?- X =.. Y.
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

This means that we cannot use this construct to **generate** solutions. It works *only* if its arguments are sufficiently instantiated.

Second, using `(=..)/2` also comes with the **time and memory overhead** of constructing and representing a list *in addition* to the term that is already there in a different form. (And, *mutatis mutandis*, in the other direction too of course.)

Thus, it may be worth to ask: Are there different ways to solve this task? Are they better suited?

## Alternative 1: Doing it manually

> How do I convert thee? Let me count the ways.

From the example you cite, we must be able to handle—in order of their appearance—terms of the following forms:

- `atm/3`
- `atm/1`
- `atm/2`
- `atm/4`

The point here is that the number of shown cases is **finite**, and so we can easily handle them all like this:

```
atm_list(atm(A),       [A]).
atm_list(atm(A,B),     [A,B]).
atm_list(atm(A,B,C),   [A,B,C]).
atm_list(atm(A,B,C,D), [A,B,C,D]).
```

To convert a *list* of such terms, you can use `maplist/2`:

```
?- Ls = [atm(abd,bubu,ha), atm(aei),atm(xyz,huhu), atm(aabb,a,e,x)],
   maplist(atm_list, Ls, Lists).
Ls = [atm(abd, bubu, ha), atm(aei), atm(xyz, huhu), atm(aabb, a, e, x)],
Lists = [[abd, bubu, ha], [aei], [xyz, huhu], [aabb, a, e, x]].
```

A major advantage is that this relation is very **general** and can also be used to **generate** answers:

```
?- atm_list(A, Ls).
A = atm(_27464, _27466, _27468),
Ls = [_27464, _27466, _27468] ;
A = atm(_27464),
Ls = [_27464] ;
A = atm(_27464, _27466),
Ls = [_27464, _27466] ;
A = atm(_27464, _27466, _27468, _27470),
Ls = [_27464, _27466, _27468, _27470].
```

This is also **more efficient** than using `(=..)/2`. Clearly, it can only be done if the number of arising cases is *finite*. (**Exercise**: Write a Prolog program that *generates* clauses for all integers 1..N).

## Alternative 2: Using lists

There are several well-known criteria for judging whether **lists** are an appropriate data structure. For example:

- Does the *empty list* make sense in your use case?
- Are there sensible cases for *all* possible lengths?
- etc.

Only you can answer this question for your particular use case, so I only show what it *could* look like: Suppose you represent your whole initial list as follows:

```
[[abd,bubu,ha],[aei],[xyz,huhu],[aab,a,e,x]]
```

Then the whole issue **does not even arise**, because the elements *are* already specified as lists. Thus, there is no more need to convert anything.